# I have this text file. I thought it looked like ASCII, but apparently it isn't. Tried decoding it, but no luck. Any clue as to how I can decode it?

Tags: text, encoding

I have never seen this before in my life, and am trying to decode it as best as possible. I'll include a small portion off the encoded data below:

ƒžk€‚u¶{ƒyƒj†€e€{{a€sŒyÝGU†ƒtC¨„Ž‰i€|‚…€€ƒx€xUer€‚C€Ix”éƒŒƒv‹¢t~kr˜å‰o€º€p…‚z€€~Œ„†MM´¾p€º…€}{ƒ–€€–€u˜~ùwa˜q
Š}
twvc|kŽ
tnvy*‚}€€†ƒ‹ƒg€„Õ|¢€*€€}ƒ[„~€{€‹u{Õ‚p€éƒ¤K‚v›²}€z{xi²ù‹dýdÁKm‚Ýo~‘ý“gA®C}x…Q›‘ž‚zƒ€Œ‹ck™†„€ù–Žy…¼Ù~|‚.dwÑ¶€A|u“€pt‚‡€…A:„*€€†Ù€åŠ{—õ˜ÉKa…„|*¸€{É6‚€€€ˆ€"wí~ñ€‚_†w¢v‚j€‚‹‰‚|ñ¶€‰’å_w‡•z{€ŽU‹€„ùIU|Gu”x´|É€n“•w€„ooS¬’}h‚
—€Šuq€Õt2€–yÝtyb†Šy™†¶€˜a€ƒ†€IÑÁ‚„vƒ™“e€„{Q€r¦U€í¾}€k‚’M€]z~aõe†u†E˜‹Ñ€&G•{€|¤Wy‰šƒ‚~Žpy€.]}pU¾ƒÙŠ°€C|{~‚~€œž~¾¸~q€†¨‹ƒ…Å}c}”~|…õƒ€s–*m„–†€o€_ty…pªõ.&Œ”ˆl*f…c

If anyone has any idea as to what this could possibly be, please don't hesitate to let me know!

Comment: Are you  sure it is just plain text and not a binary file? If so do you know in which language it is written?  It could be Chinese, Japanese, Thai, Hindi in UTF8 or a specific encoding... Not sure you will be able to read it even with the right encoding

Comment: You could also look for a charset decode. Have a look at http://www.webatic.com/run/chars/charset_decoder.php